# how to parse xml using DOM in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

i use this code to parse a xml data in java but give me a errors:

```
    Informations info=new Informations();
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/XML");
    String xml="";
    xml = readUrl(conn);     
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        Document dom = db.parse(is);
        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("deal");


        //----titre
        NodeList titre = dom.getElementsByTagName("titre");
        Element line = (Element) titre.item(0);
        info.setTitre(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        System.out.println("Titre: " + info.getTitre());
       //----reduction
        NodeList reduction = dom.getElementsByTagName("reduction");
        line = (Element) reduction.item(0);
        info.setReduction(getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        System.out.println("Reduction: " + info.getReduction());
```

this is the xml  data:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<deals>
 <deal>
  <type>Occasion</type>
  <datedebutdeal>0000-00-00 00:00:00</datedebutdeal>
  <datefindeal>2014-04-30 00:00:00</datefindeal>  
  <reduction>25.93</reduction>
  <titre>A4</titre>
 </deal>
</deals>
```

its give me this errors in this part in the code :

```
  Document dom = db.parse(is);
```

this is the error:

```
[Fatal Error] :2069:1: XML document structures must start and end within the same   entity.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem but shouldn't the first line of your XML be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?

Comment: i can't change it, because i receive the data from the server

Comment: If you cant change the first line, then try skipping the first line and parse the rest of the XML.

Comment: Its Okey i remove it from the server and its work correctly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your xml must be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, otherwise it is considered as a tag and hence the error.

Comment: i can't change it, because i receive the data from the server

Comment: In that case, you could either check if the declaration is correct and add the `?` if it is not there or you just remove the entire line, as declaration is not mandatory for xml parsing, although it is recommended.

Comment: Its Okey i remove it from the server and its work correctly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your XML is incorrect. Change it to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: i can't change it, because i receive the data from the server

Comment: You can either talk to the server's sys admin about it, modify that first line, or remove the first line before sending it to the DocumentBuilder.

Comment: Its Okey i remove it from the server and its work correctly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could replace first line of xml by adding `xml = xml.replaceFirst("<xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");`
after `xml = readUrl(conn);`.

Answer (score 0):

Two workarounds:
Just before the sentence: Document dom = db.parse(is); you should read entire inputstream in a string and remove the invalid line .
Otherwise, if server don't resolve the bug, you can replace the first line with